# Additional viewing options on html slideshow

Tags: html, css, image, slideshow

I'm using a slideshow on my website, basic functions...left and right buttons.

For some of the images, it would be nice to have an additional viewing option, where there would be mini images to the right of the main slide show image, and if you click on an individual image, it would replace the main image with that.

My reasoning is, this is an art website, and for some works it would be nice to view it from a different angle.

Does anyone know any good examples of something like this?

For reference, this is what I'm more or less using at the moment: http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_slideshow_self

Thank you for any help.

Comment: go to dynamic drive, there are probably ready made solutions for this.

Comment: There are a ton of free javascript slideshow's out there with thumbnails. Give it a google, oh and bonus points for the profile pic lol.